# When a key is evicted from Redis, is it possible to know which keys are evicted?

Tags: redis

Lets say a Redis node is configured with an eviction policy of LRU. Whenever an key-eviction takes place, is there way to know which keys are evicted?

Using this information, I would like to build a system where evicted keys are streamed to another database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at Redis keyspace notifications. https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

With the RedisGears module you can react to these keyspace notifications.

In RedisGears 2 you can register your consumer, and then push information from there to the stream. But this is happening after the eviction has happened.

```
//Second argument is to set a prefix for keys you want to filter on
redis.register_notifications_consumer("eviction_consumer", "", function(client, data) {
    //Do checks here
    
    client.call('XADD', data.key, ...);
});
```

There is an extensive get started in the [RedisGears repository](https://github.com/RedisGears/RedisGears).